# Printing values inside for loop gives different results if you print by index or by value

Tags: r

I'm trying to understand why I get different results when I print the values of the list when I access them by index or just by directly:

```
ws <- c(as.Date('2016-01-01'))

for (w in ws) {
  print(w)  
}
# prints 16801

for (idx in 1:length(ws)) {
  print(ws[idx])
}
# prints 2016-01-01
```

I'm not sure why the first time, when I access the value using `in` I get the wrong value.

How can I print the values directly accessing via `in` (not using indexes)? And also why is it happening?

Answer (score 2):

Probably because `ws` is actually an integer; the "date" you see is just for printing purposes, but the data is tracked as days since a starting point.

When you create an indexing variable `w in ws`, R is probably coercing it to be an integer so `w` has lost all "date" attributes, and all you get is the underlying integer.

Indeed, in `?Control` we see that for `seq`:

> An expression evaluating to a vector (including a list and an
>   expression) or to a pairlist or NULL. A factor value will be coerced
>   to a character vector.

And `as.vector(ws)` will return `ws` to it's underlying, integer, state.

In your second example, `ws` has remained unchanged, so printing elements from it will continue to be formatted as dates.